# Binary VTK for RECTILINEAR_GRID from fortran code

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles, vtk, paraview

I am having a fortran code to generate a grid in binary VTK format. This code produces a binary VTK file like this one:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
BINARY
DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID
DIMENSIONS        2       2       1
X_COORDINATES        2  float
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
Y_COORDINATES        2  float
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
Z_COORDINATES        1  float
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

When, I try to open it with ParaView it crashes with the following error message:

> ERROR: In
>   /home/user/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.3.0/ParaView-4.1.0/VTK/IO/Legacy/vtkRectilinearGridReader.cxx,
>   line 311 vtkRectilinearGridReader (0x379f4b0): Unrecognized keyword:
>   ...

If I write the above file in ASCII instead, then it opens properly in ParaView, that's the ASCII analogous file that opens:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID
DIMENSIONS 2 2 1
X_COORDINATES 2 float
0 1
Y_COORDINATES 2 float
0 1
Z_COORDINATES 1 float
0
```

I am using the following code to generate the grid in binary VTK format (I am giving a minimum working code):

```
program VTKBinary

implicit none

real*8    :: x(2) = (0., 1.)
real*8    :: y(2) = (0., 1.)
real*8    :: z(1) = (0.)

character :: buffer*80, lf*1, str1*8, str2*8, str3*8
integer   :: ivtk = 9, int

lf = char(10) ! line feed character

open(unit=ivtk,file='test_bin.vtk',form='binary',convert='BIG_ENDIAN')

buffer = '# vtk DataFile Version 3.0'//lf  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'vtk output'//lf                  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'BINARY'//lf                      ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID'//lf    ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)

! WRITE GRID
write(str1(1:8),'(i8)') size(x)
write(str2(1:8),'(i8)') size(y)
write(str3(1:8),'(i8)') size(z)
buffer = 'DIMENSIONS '//str1//str2//str3//lf  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'X_COORDINATES '//str1//'  float'//lf ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) x
buffer = lf//'Y_COORDINATES '//str2//'  float'//lf  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) y
buffer = lf//'Z_COORDINATES '//str3//'  float'//lf  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) z

close(ivtk)

end program VTKBinary
```

What is wrong with the binary VTK file? why it exits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is, that arrays are specified as `[0., 1.]`, not as `(0., 1.)`, that would be a complex number equal to one imaginary unit *i*. The same way `[0.]` instead of `(0.)`. Thanks to Alexander Voigt in [binary vtk for Rectilinear_grid from fortran code can not worked by paraview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299579/binary-vtk-for-rectilinear-grid-from-fortran-code-can-not-worked-by-paraview), for pointing out the issue.

You state that you use `FLOAT`, but than you store `real*8` there. They are not compatible. Either store `real*4` (or a more modern `real(real32)` ) there, or place the text `DOUBLE` instead of `FLOAT` in the file.

Note, the stand conforming `access=stream` is much better than the non-standard `form=binary`. Also, `convert=BIG_ENDIAN` is non-standard and will not work with many compilers (e.g., gfortran, if I recall it correctly). The `char(10)` is better to be `achar(10)` but that is a minor issue.

BTW,

```
buffer = 'DIMENSIONS '//str1//str2//str3//lf  ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
```

can just be

```
write(ivtk) 'DIMENSIONS '//str1//str2//str3//lf
```

Comment: I used "DOUBLE" instead of  "FLOAT" and it worked. I kept using "form=binary" and "convert=BIG_ENDIAN" for two reasons: 1) I am using intel fortran compiler, and 2) I don't know when I use "access=stream" if I can have an output file with mixed binary and ASCII data.

Comment: access=stream should work exactly the same way you have now.

Comment: `access=stream` makes the file IO work like a file in c. When writing a binary VTK file, there is no need to "mix binary and ASCII data." All data is binary. When you write out characters, such as `DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID`, you are writing out the binary representation of those characters. The text editor is able to correctly interpret and display those. It is not able to correctly interpret the floating-point data, hence all the `^@` garbage, and the impression you've got "mixed" binary and ASCII data.