# binary vtk for Rectilinear_grid from fortran code can not worked by paraview

Tags: binary, fortran, vtk, paraview

I used the code posted from stackoverflow and modified it as:

```
program VTKBinary

implicit none

real*4    :: x(2) = (0., 1.)
real*4    :: y(2) = (0., 1.)
real*4    :: z(2) = (0., 1.)

character :: buffer*80, lf*1, str1*8, str2*8, str3*8
integer   :: ivtk = 9, int,i

lf = char(10) ! line feed character

!open(unit=ivtk,file='test_bin.vtk',form='binary',convert='BIG_ENDIAN')
open(unit=ivtk,file='test_bin.vtk',access='stream',convert='BIG_ENDIAN')

buffer = '# vtk DataFile Version 3.0'//lf      ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'vtk output'//lf                      ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'BINARY'//lf                          ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID'//lf        ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)

! WRITE GRID
write(str1(1:8),'(i8)') size(x)
write(str2(1:8),'(i8)') size(y)
write(str3(1:8),'(i8)') size(z)
buffer = 'DIMENSIONS '//str1//str2//str3//lf         ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
buffer = 'X_COORDINATES '//str1//'  float'//lf                 ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
!write(ivtk) x
write(ivtk) (x(i),i=1,size(x))
buffer = lf//'Y_COORDINATES '//str2//'  float'//lf             ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
!write(ivtk) y
write(ivtk) (y(i),i=1,size(y))
buffer = lf//'Z_COORDINATES '//str3//'  float'//lf             ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
!write(ivtk) z
write(ivtk) (z(i),i=1,size(z))

close(ivtk)

end program VTKBinary
```

This code is compiled well by gfortran and it runs well to generate vtk file.

Problem: there is an error when the vtk is read by paraview as following:

```
Warning: In C:\DBD\pvs-x64\paraview\src\paraview\VTK\Rendering\Core\vtkRenderer.cxx, line 1029
vtkOpenGLRenderer (000000000BF00BF0): Resetting view-up since view plane normal is parallel
```

Question: can you help me to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you post the link you took the code from?

Comment: Since when does gfortran support `convert='BIG_ENDIAN'`?

Comment: Ok, don't know since when, but it does https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CONVERT-specifier.html#CONVERT-specifier

Comment: One of the issues might be that `(a, b)` denotes the complex number `a+ib`. To specify an array use `[a,b]`. Unfortunately, that doesn't help me debug your problem...

Comment: Well, not really suggested: "*Also, convert=BIG_ENDIAN is non-standard and will not work with many compilers (e.g., gfortran, if I recall it correctly).*"  I didn't even remember this one I corrected the answer and it turned out that after doing that they are just duplicates. Maybe people should not accept answers which don't solve the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry about, there was an issue, which was not explained in the answer there. Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was pointed out by @AlexanderVoigt. Arrays are specified as `[0., 1.]`, not as `(0., 1.)`, that would be a complex number equal to one imaginary unit *i*.

The other problem is missing `lf` at the end. Just use

```
buffer = 'X_COORDINATES '//str1//'  float'//lf             ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) x, lf
buffer = 'Y_COORDINATES '//str2//'  float'//lf             ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) y, lf
buffer = 'Z_COORDINATES '//str3//'  float'//lf             ; write(ivtk) trim(buffer)
write(ivtk) z, lf
```

It is better to always put the `lf` at the end so you do not forget it.

BTW you do not have to put the strings in a buffer and then trim it, you can even write them directly:

```
write(ivtk) 'X_COORDINATES '//str1//'  float'//lf
```

Comment: you might want to change your other answer as well... The issue with the complex notation is copied from there.

Comment: Maybe they are just duplicates after all.

Comment: I do, I see a cube from 4 points...

Comment: Many thanks Alexander,

Comment: I correct (a,b) to [a,b] and it work well. Thanks

Comment: @Cfdfan Glad I could help.

Comment: @Alexander: yes, you are right, just [a,b]