# Writing a mixof ascii and binary data in Fortran

Tags: fortran, ascii, binaryfiles, vtk

I'm trying to write a mix of ASCII and binary data as given below for a vtk file format data.

I understand that the binary or ASCII distinction must be made in a file-OPEN statement (in the FORM='BINARY', preferably: ACCESS='STREAM' ). I don't understand how to write the file for the format I require.

What I'm trying to output:

```
ascii keyword  
ascii keyword  
ascii keyword  
ascii keyword  
ascii keywords "variable value in ascii" ascii keywords   
.....SOME BINARY DATA ....
.....................
```

What I'm using:

```
write(fl) "# vtk DataFile Version 3.0"//CHAR(13)//CHAR(10)  
write(fl)"Flow Field"//CHAR(13)//CHAR(10)  
write(fl)"BINARY"//CHAR(13)//CHAR(10)  
write(fl)"DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID"//CHAR(13)//CHAR(10)  
write(fl)"POINTS",npoints,"float"    -------------> gives value of npoints(example:8) in binary format
```

What the output should be:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Flow Field
BINARY
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 8 Float
.....SOME BINARY DATA ....
.....................
```

What the output is:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Flow Field
BINARY
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTSÒ^O^@^@float
.....SOME BINARY DATA ....
...................
```

Comment: Form="Binary" isn't Fortran. Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve (rather than how you are trying to solve it) and then maybe we can suggest a solution.

Comment: @ Ian  Form='BINARY' is also a fortran format. It has roughly the same effect as FORM='UNFORMATTED', except that no record lengths are embedded in the file. I'll edit my question about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Form="Binary" is non standard and thus not supported by all compilers. You probably want Access="stream". Please see https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/676047

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!, I'll use access='stream'. I have updated what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will find examples of writing of VTK files on the internet, like in questions [binary vtk for Rectilinear_grid from fortran code can not worked by paraview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299579/binary-vtk-for-rectilinear-grid-from-fortran-code-can-not-worked-by-paraview) and [Binary VTK for RECTILINEAR_GRID from fortran code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023262/binary-vtk-for-rectilinear-grid-from-fortran-code) in various open source research codes, like https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/866794b5f95ec93351b0edea47e52af8eadeceb5/src/simplevtk.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default (this one is my simplified example, there are many more) or in dedicated libraries, like http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/vtk_io/vtk_io.html (there is also a VTKFortran library for the XML VTK files).

Socondly, even though you are on Windows, you should not use the Windows line ending conventions in VTK binary files. End your lines just with `achar(10)` (or the `new_line` constant from `iso_fortran_env`). And don't forget that the binary data must be bigendian. There are examples how to deal with that in the links above.

Thirdly, to put an integer number to a string, we have a huge number of duplicates. I mean *really* huge. Start here [Convert integers to strings to create output filenames at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time) and I will shamelessly recommend my `itoa` function there, because it will simplify your code a lot.

```
write(fl)"POINTS ",itoa(npoints)," float"
```

Comment: `I will shamelessly recommend my itoa function there, because it will simplify your code a lot.`

I will shamelessly use it, it's a good simple function.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace

```
write(fl)"POINTS",npoints,"float"
```

with

```
BLOCK
   integer, parameter :: big_enough = 132 ! Or whatever
   character(big_enough) line
   write(line,'(*(g0))')"POINTS ",npoints," Float"//achar(13)//achar(10)
   write(f1) trim(line)
END BLOCK
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a pgi compiler and it doesn't support Block Construct

Comment: The only reason for `BLOCK` was so that I could isolate the declarations. If you moved the *specification-part* of the `BLOCK` construct into the *specification-part* of the enclosing scope you wouldn't need to use the high input impedance `BLOCK` construct.